# Invalid reference Account.BillingCountryCode of type sobjectField in file accountCreator.js

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I try to get salesforce default field but failed.
error messsage is:

> force-app/main/default/lwc/accountCreator/accountCreator.js  Invalid
> reference Account.BillingCountryCode of type sobjectField in file
> accountCreator.js

my code here:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import ParentId_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.ParentId';
import BillingCountryCode_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingCountryCode';
import BillingCountry_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingCountry';

const fields = [NAME_FIELD, ParentId_FIELD, BillingCountry_FIELD, BillingCountryCode_FIELD];

export default class AccountCreator extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
  account;

  get name() {
    return getFieldValue(this.account.data, NAME_FIELD);
  }

  get parentId() {
    return getFieldValue(this.account.data, ParentId_FIELD);
  }

  get countryCode() {
    return getFieldValue(this.account.data, BillingCountryCode_FIELD);
  }

  get country() {
    return getFieldValue(this.account.data, BillingCountry_FIELD);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('recordId==', this.recordId, ' ACCOUNT_OBJECT==', ...ACCOUNT_OBJECT);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your org have State and Country Picklists turned on?

Comment: Yes, I did it as you suggested to turn on "State and Country/Territory Picklists" a few days ago and it worked, but today it doesn't work, I go to SetUp to check it again, the "State and Country/Territory Picklists" is still enabled, do you know why?